# Integration from MVC2 .net 3.5 to MVC3 .net 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, migration

Like to know what are the step need to do for integrating MVC2 .net 3.5 to MVC3 .net 4.0 without using any upgrading tool.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing this should require is a .NET framework upgrade on the box serving IIS.  Any MVC2 .NET 3.5 app should work seamlessly side-by-side with an MVC3 .NET 4.0 app.